# Flutter FadeInImage Network - Will not fade in image on setState image change

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a widget that uses FadeInImage.assetNetwork to load image, first time when the App loads, the image fade in of image works fine, while i try to update the Image URL state, the FadeInImage option doesn't work.

The Below widget is used to load the image, where qIcon is set dynamically on setState.

```
  Widget quizIconCard(qIcon) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              height: 128,
              width: 128,
              placeholder: 'assets/login_logo.png',
              image: qIcon,
              imageScale: 1.2,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The setState for `qIcon` updates the image URL, but we do not see the fadeIn effect nor the placeholder image.

Any work around on this ?

Comment: That's the designed behavior of [FadeInImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html). *"When either placeholder or image changes, this widget continues showing the previously loaded image (if any) until the new image provider provides a different image."* You'll probably have to do something that replaces the entire widget.

Comment: Yes, that worked - tried reloading the widget, could you post that as an answer ?

Comment: I posted that as a comment because I didn't feel like it was a complete answer since I wasn't able to provide a code example, but I've gone ahead and moved it to an answer since it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of [`FadeInImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) indicates that the fade only takes place once after the initial image loads, and any subsequent changes will just result in the image being replaced.

> When either placeholder or image changes, this widget continues
>   showing the previously loaded image (if any) until the new image
>   provider provides a different image.

That means you will likely need to implement your image change in such a way that a new widget is generated instead of just changing the URL.